Heavy quark pair production from electron-positron annihilation in NLO QCD
I am considering the process of electron-positron annihilation resulting in a quark-antiquark pair. The total cross section for this process, up to next-to-leading order (NLO) in QCD (i.e. including up to 1 radiated gluon), neglecting weak interactions, was calculated here, and also in [Foundations of Quantum Chromodynamics by Taizo Muta, 3rd ed.], section 5.1, both for the massless quark case. The result is famously a correction factor
$$
\frac{3}{4}\frac{C_F \alpha_s}{\pi}
$$
with respect to the leading order QED result. It is also given as the first "Final Project" in [
An Introduction To Quantum Field Theory by Peskin & Schroeder]
I have now performed this same calculation in NLO QCD, again neglecting weak interactions, but without assuming massless quarks. After renormalizing the loop diagram, the remaining IR divergences from the loop and gluon radiation diagrams cancel (as they should), and a final, finite, complicated function of $\beta=\sqrt{1-\frac{4m^2}{s}}$, involving logarithms and dilogarithms, remains in place of the constant $\frac{3}{4}$ (corresponding to the case $\beta=1$).
I have found papers doing this calculation from hadron collisions, but not from electron-positron annihilation. Could someone point me to a textbook, or a paper, where this calculation was performed, so I can check my answer? I imagine there should be some interest in this, with an eye to a future electron-positron collider producing top quark pairs? Thanks!
